# Test a method which uses external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I have a model called `Video`. This model has a `after_save` callback which runs a method `#upload_video_to_depot`. That method uses `:file` param (which is not saved in the db) and uploads a video file to a remote API using `RestClient`.

The question is - how to handle that in my specs without actually sending the file to the API ? I need to test my `Video` model and `#upload_video_to_depot` method but i can't imagine how it should be done (i'm quite fresh in the TDD thing).

Can it be fully handled in the specs or it also involves some changes in my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a gem like [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) to stub external requests. You can set expectations on what requests were sent and with what params, as well as the responses the server should be giving you.

This will allow you to ensure that your REST client is sending the correct params to the correct place and processing responses correctly.